# Running Python script parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a huge dataset of videos that I process using a python script called `process.py`. The problem is it takes a lot of time to process all the dataset which contains 6000 videos. So, I came up with the idea of dividing this dataset for example into 4 and copy the same code to different Python scripts (e.g. `process1.py`, `process2.py`, `process3.py`, `process3.py`) and run each one on different shells with one portion of the dataset.

My question is would that bring me anything in terms of performance? I have a machine with 10 cores so it would be very beneficial if I could somehow exploit this multicore structure. I heard about `multiprocessing` module of Python but unfortunately, I don't know much about it and I didn't write my script considering that I would use its features. Is the idea of starting each script in different shells nonsense? Is there a way to choose which core would be used by each script?

Comment: Which OS? Windows or Linux, for example.

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 17):

The `multiprocessing` documentation ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) is actually fairly easy to digest. This section (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) should be particularly relevant

You definitely do not need multiple copy of the same script. This is an approach you can adopt:

Assume it is the general structure of your existing script (`process.py`).

```
def convert_vid(fname):
    # do the heavy lifting
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # There exists VIDEO_SET_1 to 4, as mentioned in your question
   for file in VIDEO_SET_1:  
       convert_vid(file)
```

With `multiprocessing`, you can fire the function `convert_vid` in seperate processes. Here is the general scheme:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def convert_vid(fname):
    # do the heavy lifting
    # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
   pool = Pool(processes=4) 
   pool.map(convert_vid, [VIDEO_SET_1, VIDEO_SET_2, VIDEO_SET_3, VIDEO_SET_4])
```

Comment: would mind checking (stackoverflow.com/questions/68305077/…). I am trying to apply the idea you gave but I am not sure how I can pass different datasets and dataset name